# Closures in functions and objects

Tags: javascript, closures

Snippets below do exactly the same.
First one:

```
var obj_button = {
    clicked: 1,
    click: function() {
        console.log(clicked);
    }
};
```

Second one:

```
var Func_button = function() {
    var clicked = 1;
    this.click = function() {
        console.log(clicked);
    }
}
```

But when i want to make use of closures, the first approach fails:

```
func = new Func_button();
func.click(); // OK - works fine, outputs 1
obj_button.click(); // FAIL - he don't know what is "clicked"
```

So my question is: why in first approach, method click() has no ability to see "clicked" param. Shouldn't closure cover this param (just like in second example) ?

Comment: In your first example, the function **is** a closure, it tries to access a variable called `clicked`. If it is not defined, you will get this error.

Comment: For one thing you should have a semicolong after the assignment `= function () { [code] }**;**`

Answer (score 4):

No, because `clicked` in the first instance is in the object scope while in the second instance it is in the function scope.  `this.click = function` is also within the function scope, but the contents of `click: function () {` are in a different scope.

For the first example to work, you can use:

```
console.log(this.clicked);
```

You can also see the same behavior if you rewrite your second example:

```
var Func_button = function() {
    this.clicked = 1;
    this.click = function() {
        console.log(clicked);
    };
}
```

Now, `func.clicked` will return `1`, but calling `func.click()` will result in the same error.

Comment: But In JavaScript, scopes are declared by functions, and not by blocks. Can we talk about "objects scope" ?

Comment: @przemeko The "Object Scope" is a bit different; it's not considered it's own block, but essentially there is no `clicked` variable in any scope.  It's `this.clicked` that's in whatever the current scope is.